# Angular app cannot handle ESP32 web server REST endpoints

Tags: angular, rest, iot

I am building Angular application reading data from WIFI enabled microcontrolers. Specifically I have 2 different weather servers exposing weather conditions to the app. Both work and the call to them returns something like this:

[image]

image shows the call to Raspberry Pico micropython server serving json payload, the second one works on ESP32 and C and serves plain text as json:

[image]

My problem is that calling those endpoints from angular application fails with the following error:

[image]

Both endpoints cause the same issue and I don't understand the problem actually. It works in browser but not in angular app saying that they return undefined ?

Here is the angular component code reading the endpoint :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.weatherService.getAtmoConditions().subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.weatherConditions = res;
            this.dataLoaded = Promise.resolve(true);
        });
    }
```

service code looks like this:

```
getAtmoConditions(): Observable<WeatherConditions> {
        const url = this.getServiceUrl() + environment.GET_ALL;
        console.log(url);
        return this.http.get<WeatherConditions>(url);
    }
```

url translates to either of those:

```
KITCHEN_ATMO_ENDPOINT: 'http://192.168.0.18/weather/',
GARAGE_ATMO_ENDPOINT: 'http://192.168.0.20/weather/',
```

Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Would be helpful if you also show the code which retrieves the data. Without this, we can only guess where the problem lies.

Comment: failr enough, it's added

Comment: The code looks fine. I'm assuming that the `ngOnInit()` method is the one that is mentioned in the stack trace. So let's check some points, since the error lies somewhere else. The `HttpClientModule` is imported? There is only one `WeatherService` so the import is correct? Do you use an `HttpInterceptor`?

Comment: HttpInterceptor was exactly the issue, I forgot about this guy. Thanks Lars

Comment: Lasr, if you collect point, create and answer please and I'll close this

Comment: Nice, wasn't really sure if this was exactly the error message if you forgot to return the observable in the interceptor. Will create a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, the error lies somewhere else. Based on the error message, it's something where an observable is expected but `undefined` is returned.
If you use a `HttpInterceptor`, it could be that the intercepted request is not returned there, so make sure, to return the observable of the `HttpHandler`.

```js
return next.handle(request);
```